# How do I change a single value inside a localStorage item?

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have a set of items that get saved but I'm trying to change a value after I retrieve it and before I pass it of to my php function.  Is it possible to change just one item?

My string of items looks like this:

```
var args = window.localStorage.getItem("localusers");

start=0&type=1
```

I'm saving the localusers item like so:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('localusers', $("#profile_form_id").serialize());
```

I'm trying to set the value of type to a 6

I can't find a supported method that allows me to get/set an item in the array so do I need to iterate through the array, change the value and then set the localusers item again?  It doesn't seem very efficient but I can't see any other way.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`localstorage` does not return an array or an object. It can only store a string.

The way people get around it, is to `JSON.stringify()` the array/object before passing it to `setItem`. Then, when retrieving it with `getItem()`, you run `JSON.parse()` on it.

Assuming this is an object, and you've parsed it, you can modify your `args` variable before you send it along:

```
args.type = 6;
```

---

To ease all this, here's a little helper that you can call:

```
var localstorage = {
    set: function (key, value) {
        window.localStorage.setItem( key, JSON.stringify(value) );
    },
    get: function (key) {
        try {
            return JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem(key) );
        } catch (e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
};
```

If you include this script, you can then set and get items through `localstorage.get` and `localstorage.set`, and it'll automatically convert it to & from JSON.

Comment: So I should call JSON.stringify() before setting it?  I currently set it like this: window.localStorage.setItem('localusers', $("#profile_form_id").serialize());

Comment: @Paul: returned from what? `localstorage` does not return an array/object!

Comment: @Paul: you are using `.serialize()` incorrectly. `.serialize()` creates a url string out of your fields. If you want an array of objects, you should use `.serializeArray()`. You can read about it here: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var args = window.localStorage.getItem("localusers");
args["type"] = 6;

//Update the localStorage with new value
localStorage.setItem("localusers", JSON.stringify(args));
```

Like other `JavaScript` objects, you can treat the `localStorage` object as an associative array. Instead of using the `getItem()` and `setItem()` methods, you can simply use square brackets.

```
var args = localStorage["localusers"];
args["type"] = 6;

//Update the localStorage with new value
localStorage["localusers"] = args;
```

Comment: Is one method better or more efficient/flexible between the two mentioned?

Comment: I think using square bracket is better than calling the method.

Comment: Why even use square brackets? Wouldn't dot notation work just as well (`localStorage.localusers`, `args.type`, etc.)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working...is it because I'm saving my localStorage item as serialized data? I'm saving my data like so: localStorage["localusers"] = $("#profile_form_id").serialize();

Comment: When you get the item from localStorage, can you debug and see what you get?

Comment: looks like the URL string: online=1&type=1&start=0

Comment: Thats where the problem is. Use `JSON.stringify` to serialize the form fields and then store in localStorage. After retreiving it from localStorage you should use `$.parse` method to convert it into json object and then modify it.

Comment: Even trying to print out the type shows undefined.  Here is how I'm now saving: window.localStorage.setItem('localusers', JSON.stringify($("#profile_form_id").serialize())); and retrieving it again:  var args = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("localusers")); alert("TYPE: " + args["type"]); What am I missing?

Comment: localStorage only supports strings.  this will not work unless you serialize/de-serialize the 'localusers' value after/before modifying the args property.

Comment: Where in my answer I mentioned that you can store anything? Please read my answer before down voting.

Comment: Not until the code in the answer doesn't try to change the "type" property of args (a string) and then "Update localStorage with new value" by doing localStorage.setItem('localusers', args).  That's nonsense.

Comment: Edited my answer take a look.