# How do I change a single value inside a localStorage item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I'm trying to change a value inside localstorage. This item is the status of a checkbox. I want, everytime that a checkbox is checked to set the value to true or false of that checkbox. I tried many ways until I realized that there is no way you can change a value without using JSON.

To add the value I use:

```
localStorage.setItem("status-" + i, $status.is(":checked"));
```

and to delete I use:

```
var parentId = $this.parent().attr('id');
localStorage.removeItem("'" + parentId + "'");
```

Now to change the value I tried:

```
$itemList.delegate("#status-" + i, 'click', function(e) {

                var $this = $(this);
                var parentId = this.parent().attr('id');            

                if ($this.is(":checked")) { 

                    localStorage.setItem("'" + parentId + "'".val("fdgsdagf"));
                    // Note that alert here works.

                }
});
```

This is how my local storage looks like:
[image]
I hope someone could help me. I've been working on it for few days...

Thanks alot

Answer (score 5):

`setItem` takes two parameters:

```
localStorage.setItem('status-1', "'" + parentId + "'".val("fdgsdagf"));
```

or more likely for your case:

```
localStorage.setItem(parentId, "fdgsdagf");
```

Best Practices:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(value));
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/F8sF2/

EDIT: from you fiddle, you need to change:

```
var parentId = this.parent().attr('id');
```

to

```
var parentId = $this.attr('id');
```

UPDATED http://jsfiddle.net/CC5Vw/1/

Comment: unfortunately none of both work. I tweaked them aswell in case anything similar works but yet again nothing works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207337/how-do-i-change-a-single-value-inside-a-localstorage-item On this post, a guy says you can't change the item's value without JSON. But the way he does it is abit confusing. Thanks

Comment: I think you would want `$this.attr('id')`, not parent as well

Comment: but it doesn't change the value of the status. Check: http://fiddle.jshell.net/CC5Vw/1/show/ with firebug.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question asked by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
localStorage.setItem(parentId, "fdgsdagf");
```

`localStorage` is nothing but JavaScript object you can treat them as associate array. So you can use them like this.

To set value

```
localStorage[parentId] = "fdgsdagf";
```

To get  value

```
var status = localStorage[parentId];
```

Comment: I think I will need to use the 'i' since I have "var i = Number(localStorage.getItem('todo-counter')) + 1," so that each time the checkbox increases value. Thank you